# Why does rustc say that the variable "totalSplitInv" is out of scope?

Tags: scope, rust

I ran the following program past rustc:

```
#![feature(slicing_syntax)]
fn sortAndCountInv(arr: &mut [i64]) -> i64 {
    return sortAndCountInv_(arr, 0, arr.length - 1)
}

fn sortAndCountInv_(arr: &mut [i64], start: i64, finish: i64) {
    let lengthOfSubarray = finish - start + 1;
    if (lengthOfSubarray == 0) || (lengthOfSubarray == 1) {
        return totalSplitInv
    }
    else {
        let half = (start + finish) / 2;
        let leftInv = sortAndCountInv_(arr, start, half);
        let rightInv = sortAndCountInv_(arr, half + 1, finish);
        let splitInv = mergeAndCountSplitInv(arr, start, finish, half);
        return leftInv + rightInv + splitInv
    }
}
fn mergeAndCountSplitInv(arr: &mut [i64], start: i64, finish: i64, half: i64) -> i64 {
    let aux = arr[start..finish + 1];
    let divider = half - start;
    let mut i = 0;
    let mut j = divider + 1;
    let mut totalSplitInv = 0;
    let lastIndex = aux.length - 1;
    for k in range(start, finish + 1) {
        if i > divider {
            arr[k] = aux[j];
            j += 1
        } else if j > lastIndex {
            arr[k] = aux[i];
            i += 1
        } else if aux[i] < aux[j] {
            arr[k] = aux[i];
            i += 1
        } else {
            arr[k] = aux[j];
            j += 1;
            totalSplitInv += (divider - i) + 1; 
        }
    }
    return totalSplitInv
}
```

When I try to compile it with rustc v-0.12.0-dev, I get the following scope error:

```
inversions.rs:9:16: 9:29 error: unresolved name `totalSplitInv`.
inversions.rs:9         return totalSplitInv
```

Which is to say, in the function `mergeAndCountSplitInv`, the line `return totalSplitInv` is invalid because totalSplitInv is out of scope? Why is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error is pointing to the `return totalSplitInv` in `sortAndCountInv_`, not `mergeAndCountSplitInv`.

```
fn sortAndCountInv_(arr: &mut [i64], start: i64, finish: i64) {
    let lengthOfSubarray = finish - start + 1;
    if (lengthOfSubarray == 0) || (lengthOfSubarray == 1) {
        return totalSplitInv // here
...
```